# Network calling using Dio is not working and returns error code 400

Tags: flutter, api, dio

I need to call the below api, I am trying to do this from one day, tried so many example and so many ways but I didn't succeeded I am really exhausted host is reachable but every example is giving different errors

URL: http://192.168.1.67:36211/api/Account/UserLogin

json is

```
{
    "AuthToken": {
        "AuthKey": "FJ1189A002023",
        "AuthToken": "",
        "AuthValue": "",
        "LoginTimeStamp": "2022-06-07 10:08:15.316",
        "RequestNumber": 1,
        "UserID": "1"
    },
    "EntityObject": {
        "ClientMAC": "02:00:00:00:00:00",
        "MailID": "kia@gmail.com",
        "PasswordEncrypted": "KIA",
        "SessionIdentifier": "192.168.1.186"
    }
}
```

Here AuthToken object values are hardcoded.

Last tried approach is

```
void userLogin() async{
    EntityObject eo = EntityObject(mailID: userName,passwordEncrypted: password);
    AuthToken ao = AuthToken();
    WMSCoreMessage wmsCoreMessage = WMSCoreMessage(entityObject: eo,authToken: ao);
    //final data = wmsCoreMessage.toJson();
   
    var url = Apis.login2;
    Response response = await Dio().post(url,
        data: wmsCoreMessage);
    print('response : $response');

}
```

What is the wrong thing I am doing can any one guide me how to do this,

Answer (score 0):

**The problem might not be from your side, the server may be actually down and not reachable.**

If you want to test any host to see if it is reachable or not and also to check the consumed time to reach it you can run the simple `ping` command in the Terminal or Command Prompt:

Example for [www.google.com](https://www.google.com):

```
ping google.com
```

Output:

```
Pinging google.com [172.217.171.206] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.171.206: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=117
Reply from 172.217.171.206: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=117
Reply from 172.217.171.206: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=117
Reply from 172.217.171.206: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=117

Ping statistics for 172.217.171.206:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 38ms, Maximum = 39ms, Average = 38ms
```

or the IP of your API:

```
ping 192.168.1.67
```

Output:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.67 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.67:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

You can see that when we pinged [google.com](https://www.google.com) we received a replay from it but when we tried a down host we haven't received any packets.

Comment: Hi sawaf, its not about pinging issue. I am able to ping the ip but im getting err400 and now after doing some changes in my code I am getting this error:  DioError [DioErrorType.connectTimeout]: Connecting timed out [0ms]

Comment: Please help me to get the response

Comment: Can you please share the output of the ping operation?

Comment: your ping response is not working why means it is a protected network, you need to connect to vpn to connect 192.168.1.67 this Ip

Comment: `Pinging 192.168.1.67 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.67: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.67: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.67: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.67: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.67:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 43ms, Maximum = 50ms, Average = 46ms`

Comment: and I shared my answer, as I said it is not ping issue , it is related to interceptors

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution to my problem

Flutter modified the interceptor on request and this is not mentioned in any other sources

try the below answer, May be it will be helpful to the flutter newbee's like me

API interceptor class

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class ApiInterceptors extends Interceptor {
  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
    print('requesting');
    // do something befor e request is sent
    print("${options.method} | ${options.baseUrl}  | ${options.headers} | ${options.path} | ${options.uri} | ${options.data}");
    super.onRequest(options, handler); //add this line
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioError dioError, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
    handler.next(dioError);
    print('done');
    // do something to error
    super.onError(dioError, handler); //add this line
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print('response');
    // do something before response
    super.onResponse(response, handler);//add this line
  }
}
```

API service call

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class APIService {
  Dio? _dio;

  final baseUrl = Apis.login3;
  
  APIService() {
    _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      connectTimeout: 60000,
      receiveTimeout: 60000,
      // headers: {'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    ));

    initializeInterceptors();
  }

  Future<Response?> getRequest(String endPoint) async {
    Response? response;

    try {
      response = await _dio?.get(endPoint);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }

    return response;
  }

  Future<Response?> postRequest(String endPoint, Object o) async {
    Response? response;

    try {
      response = await _dio?.post(endPoint, data: o);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }

    return response;
  }

 
  initializeInterceptors() {
    _dio?.interceptors.add(ApiInterceptors());
  }
}
```

Call the method like

```
APIService apiservice = APIService();
apiservice.postRequest(url,body);
```

thats it !!!